# adding empty bytes to end of write statement in fortran

Tags: fortran

I have a bunch of parameters which are being written out but I want to add an extra 256 bytes to that line.

```
open (1, file=filename, form='unformatted')
write (1) a,b,c,d,BLANKBYTES
write (1) array1
write (1) array2
close (1)
```

Is there a way to add these extra 'blank' bytes?

Comment: What is a blank byte ?  One whose bits are all `0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV

integer (int8), dimension (256), parameter :: zero_bytes = 0

....

write (1) a,b,c,d, zero_bytes
```

Comment: shouldn't that dim be 256/8?

Comment: int8 is 8 bits.   Also, if your compiler doesn't have the ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, you could use ISO_C_BINDING and C_INT8_T instead.  The gfortran manual documents these.

Comment: ahh. gfortran also has an intrinsic function int8() which converts to 8 *bytes*. Not to be confusing..

Comment: The gfortran int8 intrinsic function is a GNU extension.  That's a danger with extensions ... the language standard committee won't necessarily pay attention to them.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.

```
   write(1)a,b,c,d,(char(0),i=1,256)
```